# Mail function is not working on Google Spredsheet when HTML form with GAS

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've created a HTML form file using **Google apps script** and combine it with a spreadsheet. But in GAS the funciton SendConfirmationMail is not working for me. Here I've included both script file for expert understanding and feedback me as well.

**code.gs**

```
//Global variable
template = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index");
username = template.username;
sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Spreadsheet ID").getActiveSheet();

// Get data from HTML form
function doGet(){
  return template;
}

// Post data from HTML form to SpreadSheet
function AddToSheet(username, useremail, comment){
  return sheet.appendRow([username, useremail, comment]);
}

// send email
 function SendConfirmationMail() {
   var message, usermail;
   var sendername = "Dizaraj Dey";
   var subject = "Confirmation Mail";

usermail = template.useremail;

message = "<html><body>”
 +"Hi <b>" +username+ "!!!</b> <br><br> Your request has been successfully submitted. <br>"
+</body></html>"; 

   GmailApp.sendEmail(usermail, subject, message, 
                      {usermail, name: sendername, htmlBody: message});
 }
```

**index.html**

```
<script>
  function onFailure(error) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
</script>

<script>
  function onSuccess() {
  alert("Submission successful. Please check your email.");
}
</script>

<script>
 function formSubmit() {
            google.script.run.doSomething(document.forms[0]);
        }
</script>

<form id="theform">
<input type="text" name="name" id="username" placeholder="Input your name"/>< br>
<input type="email" name="email" id="useremail" placeholder="Your Email Address" /><br>
<input type="text" name="comment" id=" comment " placeholder="Your comments here" /><b><br>
<input type="submit" id="submitbtn" onclick="WriteInput()" value="Give Up" />
<input type="reset" id="btnReset" value="Reset" />
</form>


<!-- AddToSheet function -->
<script>

function WriteInput() {
    var name, email, comment;
    name = document.getElementById('username').value;
    email = document.getElementById('useremail').value;
    comment = document.getElementById('comment').value;

        google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
        .AddToSheet(username, useremail, comment);

}

</script>
```

Note:
The function **AddToSheet** is working properly.

**Thanks**
**Dizaraj Dey**

Comment: you are getting any eror?

Comment: try this: google.script.run.withFailureHandler(onFailure)
        .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
        .AddToSheet(name, email, comment);

Comment: No, I not yet received any error @Amol Tate

Comment: it seems you passing parameters different than variable

Comment: When I run the **SendConfirmationMail** function manually the spreadsheet filled with undefined and I receive mail. But when I submit the form then the spreadsheet filled properly but don't receive any mail.

Comment: can you share the script?

Answer (score 0):

Change the following function and try again

```
function AddToSheet(username, useremail, comment){
  SendConfirmationMail(username, useremail);
  return sheet.appendRow([username, useremail, comment]);
}

function SendConfirmationMail(username, email) {
   var message;
   var sendername = "Dizaraj Dey";
   var subject = "Confirmation Mail";

message = "<html><body>”
 +"Hi <b>" +username+ "!!!</b> <br><br> Your request has been successfully submitted. <br>"
+</body></html>"; 

   GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, message, {name: sendername, htmlBody: message});
 }
```

The reason you are getting undefined when you run the mail function manually is because it's not getting the data from the form. But you are not calling the mail function anywhere.

Comment: Still not working for me. For **more information** I've included a **trigger** setting on SendConfirmationMail function > From Spredsheet > **on form submit**

Comment: @dizaraj What's the error you are getting? What does the execution log say?

Comment: There are no logs for me. When I run the **SendConfirmationMail** function manually the spreadsheet filled with undefined and I receive mail but when I submit the form then the spreadsheet filled properly but don't receive any mail

Comment: @dizaraj That means both functions are working.  The reason you are getting `undefined` when you run the mail function manually is because it's not getting the data from the form.  But you are not calling the mail function anywhere.